# Tastypie Adding Custom Values (conditionally)

Tags: django, rest, tastypie, denormalization

I have a Complex Django model with (1) alot of fields and (2) dynamically generated data for this model that is not stored on the model.

**Comlex Resource:**

```
class ComplexResource(resource):
    class Meta:
        allowed_methods = ('get','put','post','delete','patch')
        queryset = Complex.objects.all()
        serializer = CustomSerializer()
        authorization = Authorization()
        authentication = Authentication()
        always_return_data  = True
        filtering = { "field_1" : ALL, "field_2" : ALL, "field_N" : ALL }
        ordering = ["field_1", "field_2", "field_n"]
```

Currently, my Complex endpoint `/m/api/v1/complex/` successfully returns STORED data on the model.

**Complex Response:**

```
{   "meta": {
        "limit": 20,
        "next": null,
        "offset": 0,
        "previous": null,
        "total_count": 1
    },
    "objects": [
        {"field_1": "foo", "field_2": "bar", ... , "field_n": "foobar"}
    ]
}
```

**Problem:**

What I would like to do is to use `prepend_urls` to add a custom endpoint which will return all of the data. This way I wouldn't have to use `dehydrate` wastefully adding data every time I called my current endpoint which can be seen here:

http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cookbook.html#adding-custom-values

**Question**

How do I go about creating a `prepend_url` which injects additional data into a resource? or is there a better design pattern for solving this altogether?

**Complex Response w/all data: /m/api/v1/complex/all/**

```
{   "meta": {
        "limit": 20,
        "next": null,
        "offset": 0,
        "previous": null,
        "total_count": 1
    },
    "objects": [
        {"field_1": "foo",
         "field_2": "bar",
          .
          .
          . 
         "field_n": "foobar",
         "advanced_field_1 : "a1",
         "advanced_field_2 : "a2",
          . 
          . 
          . 
         "advanced_field_n : "an",
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `dehydrate` was made for cases like yours. Add query set argument to determine that dehydrate should compute addition fields or not.

```
def dehydrate(self, bundle):
    if bundle.request.GET.get('attach_dynamic_fields'):
        bundle.data['my_dynamic_field_1'] = make_dynamic_field(1)
        bundle.data['my_dynamic_field_2'] = make_dynamic_field(2)
    return bundle
```

Then just use when needed:

```
/api/v1/complex/ # Gives all, no dynamic fields attached

/api/v1/complex/1/ # Gives one, no dynamic fields attached

/api/v1/complex/?attach_dynamic_fields=1 # Gives all, with dynamic fields

/api/v1/complex/1/?attach_dynamic_fields=1 # Gives one, with dynamic fields
```

Creating `prepend_url` doesn't make sense for me. Because it means rewriting Tastypie again. Which is sign that something here is not RESTful.

If you want to do it anyway you should take a look on `dispatch` method and its flow:
[Flow through request / response cycle](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resources.html#flow-through-the-request-response-cycle)

You will have to rewrite this: [dispatch](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/blob/master/tastypie/resources.py#L437) method in your `prepend_url` somehow.

Comment: Bingo, I knew there must be a simple way to do this!